# How do I change the Enrolment expiry notification text?

Tags: moodle

I have **moodle 1.9** version installed on my system. I have applied setting of sending enrollment expiry notification email to students before 5 days (under course settings).
I want to know where the email text is defined so that I can changed it according to my requirements.

Please help me on this.

Regards,

Pankaj Khurana

Answer (score 2):

The content of the email is contained (supposing you're using english) in:

```
[MOODLE_ROOT]/lang/en_utf8/moodle.php
```

For other languages, it is contained in:

```
[MOODLE_ROOT]/lang/[LANGUAGE]/moodle.php
```

Specifically, have a look to the following string:

```
$string['expirynotifystudentsemail'] = 'Dear $a->studentstr:

This is a notification that your enrolment in the course $a->course will expire in $a->threshold days.

Please contact $a->teacherstr for any further enquiries.';
```

Which is then used in:

```
[MOODLE_ROOT]/enrol/manual/enrol.php
```

Change that string and you're done.